# Error launching Outlook after VSTO installation

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I am trying to build a VSTO installer for an Outlook Ribbon Button. I have tried putting the application.manifest and the application.dll.manifest in the manifest registry key and am receiving an error both times when I launch Outlook after intallation, which I have included.

I also included my registry keys, how I am signing the manifest and both of the manifest codes (they were too large to paste).

**Error when using application.manifest**

```
System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Company/ApplicationInstaller/Application.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. ---> System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Deployment manifest is not semantically valid. ---> System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Deployment manifest identity must be strongly named.
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSemanticsForDeploymentRole()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSemanticsForDeploymentRole()
   at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.GetManifests(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
```

**Error when using application.dll.manifest**

```
System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Exception reading manifest from file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Company/ApplicationInstaller/Application.dll.manifest: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened. ---> System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Deployment manifest is not semantically valid. ---> System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: Deployment manifest requires <deployment> section.
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSemanticsForDeploymentRole()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSemanticsForDeploymentRole()
   at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.GetManifests(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
```

**Application.manifest**

https://pastebin.com/WWDGdWJC

**Application.dll.manifest**

https://pastebin.com/Xin6GTtm

[How I am Signing the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzMhF.png)

[Registry Keys Set During Install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDYbv.png)

I've been hitting my head against the wall for a  few days on this now. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!